# React - updating state from a child component does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm playing around with a React-Native project and I'm trying to implement a simple dropdown menu. After doing some research, I decided to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu) library to accomplish it.

I'm struggling to understand refs in React and here's what I mean:

I have this simple screen which renders a button with a dropdown menu at the top right using react-navigation:

```
export default function () {
 const nav = useNavigation();
 const [hideCompleted, setHideCompleted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    nav.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <ContextMenu
          hideCompleted={hideCompleted}
          handleCompletedClicked={() => {
            setHideCompleted(!hideCompleted);
          }}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, []);
}
```

And ContextMenu looks like this:

```
export default ({ hideCompleted, handleCompletedClicked }) => {
  let menuRef = useRef();

  const setMenuRef = (ref) => {
    menuRef.current = ref;
  };

  const handleHideCompleted = () => {
    menuRef.current.hide();
    handleCompletedClicked();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Menu
        ref={setMenuRef}
        button={<Button onPress={showMenu} />}>
        <MenuItem onPress={handleHideCompleted}>
          {hideCompleted ? 'Show' : 'Hide'} completed
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The issue is simple. Whenever I click `Hide completed` it works, but the second click does not. I guess I'm not passing the `hideCompleted` correctly, or not rerendering the ContextMenu component when the state of its parent changes.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are rendering the component inside useEffect that only runs at mount (empty `[]`), `ContextMenu` didn't render again with new `hideCompleted`. just add it to dependency array

---

```
   useEffect(() => {
     nav.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
       <ContextMenu
        hideCompleted={hideCompleted}
        handleCompletedClicked={() => {
          setHideCompleted(!hideCompleted);
        }}
       />
      ),
     });
   }, [hideCompleted]);
  )
```

Comment: Wow... So obvious! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is to use a callback to set state.Like this:

```
setHideCompleted((prevHideCompleted) => !prevHideCompleted);
```

In this way you useEffect won't run again on each state update.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    nav.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <ContextMenu
          hideCompleted={hideCompleted}
          handleCompletedClicked={() => {
            setHideCompleted((prevHideCompleted) => !prevHideCompleted);
          }}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, []);
```